# Change Version History only when Check-In

Tags: sharepoint-online, version-history, check-in, check-permissions

I opened a word file from Document Library, I added some new lines to my and just saved the file.

After that I right click to the file and go to verion history, I see that there is a new version .

Is it possible to only get a new version of the file when I check-in the file

Answer (score 0):

Go to the document library settings and open 'Versioning Settings'. Here you can chose to create major and minor (draft) versions on each edit. Plus, 'Require Check out' before document can be edited. In this way, when you save the document after edit, a minor version will be created, like 1.1, and when you publish your changes then only the major version will change, i.e. to 2.0.

[image]

[image]

Uploaded a file, checked it in, published, which created version 1.0
Now, Checked out the same file and edited in Word Online, which created version 1.1
[image]

now, checked in the file:
[image]

Now, published the file. Version history shows the major version is updated to 2.0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is by default if check-out is not required, you need to require check out in library versioning settings. When check-out is not required, a version is created when someone first saves a file and this version is updated when the person closes it.If that person or someone else then opens and saves the file again, another version is created.

Requiring check-out can help your team make the most of versioning, because people specifically designate when a version is to be created.A version is created only when someone checks out a file, changes it, and then checks it back in.